# Fast copy from one TrueCrypt non-system volume to another

Tags: truecrypt, clone, disk-encryption

Is it possible to perform sector by sector copy of one TrueCrypt non-system volume to another? As I see, the clone software (Maxtor MaxBlast) does not recognize the mounted disks as the suitable ones. The problem is that I have many small files and it looks like general copy will last forever/

Comment: Are the two drives exactly the same size? Are you making an exact copy of one drive onto another one?

Comment: Not actually, but all clone software I used before allowed size difference. Anyway, if I find the answer for the sames size drives, this will be already great

Comment: It will work if the destination drive is equal to or larger than the source drive, but the TrueCrypt volume will still be the same size as the original, with any remaining drive space being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on linux you could do something like `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc`.